# Creating hyperlink for Microsoft Teams call dynamically

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I wish to provide a series of Hyperlinks to my colleague where by on clicking the Teams `Hyperlink`, the `Microsoft-Teams` opens and directly calls the respective call-recipient. I have the ID/Phone number of my colleague and the list of the Phone-numbers of the all the call-recipients.

*Let me take a small detour and explain it giving an example of Google:*

With the `Latitude/Longitude` of the `Origin` and `Destination` known, the dynamic `Google Hyperlinks` can be created and on clicking those links one can directly open the Navigation application of Google between those points. It follows the following format:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Latitude_Origin,Longitude_Origin/Latitude_Destination,Longitude_Destination
```

Let's say the Origin is `Frankfurt` and Destination is `Berlin` and their respective Latitude/Longitude are as follows:

```
Frankfurt (Lat/Lon): (50.11544,8.69762)
Berlin (Lat/Lon):     (52.47790,13.33385)
```

By adding Latitude/Longitude in the format mentioned above, the Hyperlink to navigate between Frankfurt and Berlin can be created: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/50.11544,8.69762/52.4779,13.33385

In the same way I wish to do this for `Microsoft-Teams`, whereby I could create a dynamic Hyperlink. I know the ID/Phone-number of my colleague and I have the list of the phone numbers of all call recepients. The `HyperLink` for a `Teams` call looks like this:

[image: Teams Hyperlink]

Just as one can create a navigation link in Google dynamically, how can I create such a link for `Microsoft-Teams`? What's the format of the `Microsoft-Teams` Hyperlink

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/...Something_like_ID_of_Caller..../...Recipient_phone_number......
```

Ultimately, I need to provide these `Hyperlinks` inside Tableau visualization Software, so that on clicking these `Hyperlinks` one can directly make a call to the recipient, instead of opening `Microsoft-Teams` and manually typing the phone number.

Does anyone have an idea how to address this problem?

If Stackoverflow is not the right forum for these type of questions, then any suggestions on where I can post such a question? Thanks!

Comment: Below document explains how to generate deep link to call in MS Teams: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v2#generate-a-deep-link-to-a-call

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Thanks a ton Prasad. It helped me so so much. I tested it via email-ID, and it works. But, what if instead of e-Mail ID, I have phone number? I tried putting phone number `.../0?users=0049...` with country-code, but it didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: You can make an audio and video call to a combination of VoIP and PSTN users using below deep link format: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,4:<phonenumber>

Comment: Hallo! Sorry, I should have looked below. Yes, that solves my problem. Would you be so kind to write this as your answer, so that I could accept that? Thanks a lot Prasad for your useful help. Very appreciated.

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot. Happy to hear that your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate deep link to call in MS Teams using below format:

Make an audio call: `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>`

Make an audio and video call: `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>&withVideo=true`

Make an audio and video call to a combination of VoIP and PSTN users: `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,4:<phonenumber>`